# Sharing std::string across shared memory

Tags: c++, string, c++11, memory-management

I wish to share a `std::string` across processes using shared memory. However, I'm concerned about where the string object is allocated, on the stack, or heap, as this will affect the share.

Referring to this, [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/06367898-d42a-4c0d-a83f-1042c44b1b4e/strings-allocate-in-stack-or-heap)

...it says  :

> please note that in new STL (Visual Studio 2003 and 2005), the
>   std::string class uses a combined variant of allocating strings. If
>   the length is long then the string is allocated in heap area, but if
>   is short, it is stored in a preallocated area of the class

I don't know how long the string might be...I'd not like to allocate any fixed memory to it.

All I was planning to do is...

```
wstring somestring;
somestring.sppend(someOtherString); //several times
```

I suppose `wstring somestring[256]` will be on the stack and so I can share that easily. But what if I don't wish to have a size allocated? And what would happen if the size grows beyond a threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish to share a std::string across processes using shared memory.

You cannot share non-POD types across process boundaries, especially types that may allocate memory internally. There is no guarantee that the other processes use the same version of the STL, if they use the STL at all.  And even if they did, they would be using different memory managers.

You can instead allocate a fixed-length `char[]` array as the shared memory and copy the character content of the `std::string` into it.

> I suppose `wstring somestring[256]` will be on the stack and so I can share that easily.

No, you cannot.  `somestring` itself would be on the stack, but it is an array of `std::wstring` objects, and `std::wstring` cannot be shared.

> But what if I don't wish to have a size allocated? And what would happen if the size grows beyond a threshold?

Shared memory is not dynamically sizable.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. Are there any STL containers which can be shared across memory, without writing specific allocators for them?

Comment: None of the variable-sized containers, but maybe `std::array` at least.

Answer (score 0):

I endorse [Remy Lebeau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30772879/527489): generally, don't even bother considering this.

A related line of inquiry might lead some readers to https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html and especially the [STL containers in managed memory segments](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.containers) section.  However, in the two projects where we even briefly discussed doing something like this, we instead did exactly what Remy suggests!